# Converting an str array to int aray in a hybrid list in python

Tags: python

In python, Is there a way to convert strings to integers in the result list below? The purpose of the function is to generate a list of heights in feet and inches for a given range.

````
def height(x,y):
    min_to_max = []
    min_to_max.append(x)
    z = 0
    for a in min_to_max:        
        z = z+1
        min_to_max.append(str(x)+"."+str(z))
        if z==11:
            break
    min_to_max.append(y)
    return min_to_max```

x = height(2,3)

x = [2,
 '2.1',
 '2.2',
 '2.3',
 '2.4',
 '2.5',
 '2.6',
 '2.7',
 '2.8',
 '2.9',
 '2.10',
 '2.11',
 3]

Thx in advance
````

Comment: Which *integers* do you expect to get in the result? Can you provide the list that you *expect* to get?

Comment: Note that the imperial system is not compatible with decimal notation, which really represents a metric system. 2.10 is the same as 2.1 and 2.11 is less than 2.9. So please.... provide the *expected* output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily efficient, but you could loop through with a for-loop  and change each item if you know they are going to be integers

```
new_list = [int(i) for i in x]
```

Or in your case you may want to change the string to a float

```
new_list = [float(i) for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append each item to list as a `float`

```
min_to_max.append(float(str(x)+"."+str(z)))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.1, 2.11, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you pals for your prompt response! Sometimes the brain and body lost connection. Even though my brain directed us to type "float", my fingers, somehow, typed "int".

Answer (score 0):

Try this after z=z+1

```
check=float(str(x)+"."+str(z))
min_to_max.append(check)
```